# Adding type definitions for javascript functions

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I have this typescript which works:

```
import ytdl from 'react-native-ytdl';

type DirectLink = {
  url: string;
  headers: any[];
};

type VideoFormat = {
  itag: number;
  url: string;
  width: number;
  height: number;
};

type BasicInfo = {
  formats: VideoFormat[];
};

export default class YoutubeVideo {
  static root: string = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';

  async getDirectLink(id: string): Promise<DirectLink[]> {
    const url = `${YoutubeVideo.root}${id}`;
    return await ytdl(url, {quality: 'highestaudio'});
  }

  async getBasicInfo(id: string): Promise<BasicInfo> {
    const url = `${YoutubeVideo.root}${id}`;
    return await ytdl.getBasicInfo(url);
  }
}
```

Now I want to add type definitions, so I created node_modules/@types/react-native-ytdl/index.d.ts which contains :

```
export default function ytdl(link: string, options: any): Promise<any>;
```

this make `await ytdl(url, {quality: 'highestaudio'})` not complaining any more.

Now what should I do for `getBasicInfo` so that I can write ?

```
import ytdl, {getBasicInfo} from 'react-native-ytdl';
...
return await getBasicInfo(url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create your type definitions inside the `node_modules` folder.

Any top-level declaration file will do. ex:

*index.d.ts*

```
declare module 'react-native-ytdl' {

  type VideoFormat = {
    itag: number;
    url: string;
    width: number;
    height: number;
  };

  type BasicInfo = {
    formats: VideoFormat[];
  };

  interface Ytdl {
     (link: string, options: any): Promise<any>;
     getBasicInfo: (url: string | URL) => Promise<BasicInfo>;
  }

  const ytdl: Ytdl;
  export default ytdl;

  export const getBasicInfo: Ytdl['getBasicInfo']
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! A couple of questions : 1. Where should I put index.d.ts ? I tried to put in the same directory as YoutubeVideo.ts, but with no effect. 2. When I put it in node_modules/@types/react-native-ytdl/, function `ytdl` is fine, but not `getBasicInfo`. Note that in `react-native-ytdl` implementation, `getBasicInfo` is an attribute of `ytdl`.

Comment: @Philippe `index.d.ts` should typically be placed in the top-level source folder. Then include it by adding it to the list for the [`include`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include)s config in `tsconfig.json`. I have updated the answer to also indicate that `ytdl` also has a property called `getBasicInfo`

Comment: After applying your updates, there is no problem any more in VSCode editor, but when I run the program, I have `TypeError: (0 , _reactNativeYtdl.getBasicInfo) is not a function`

Comment: It's not a big issue, as `return await ytdl.getBasicInfo(url);` works. Thanks again!